# How to create insert and update columns in phpmyadmin and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to have one table column that is going to record time and date when row has been inserted, and one when it was updated.

What is a best way to achieve this, and that is compatible with MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7 versions ?

Also, how I can set everything in phpmyadmin ? Do I have to chose `date` or `date and time` -> `timestamp` as a column type ? And then what ?

I couldn't find any tutorial about this.

Comment: MySQL has initialization of such columns for both `insert` and `update` and even documents the process pretty well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html.

Comment: You couldn't find a tutorial how to create a table column in phpmyadmin ? I doubt it. You will can use DATETIME or TIMESTAMP whatever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: I still do not understand, do I make insert column TIMESTAMP and what to do for update ? How do I make that in phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database should have `timestamp` column to record last update timestamp
and `DATETIME` column to insert the date record was inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `record_inserted` DATETIME, 
  `last_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: your insert column has to be `datetime`

Comment: So for `record_inserted` I chose type `date and time` -> `DATETIME` in phpmyadmin ? And for `last_updated` there is option `date and time` -> `TIMESTAMP`, but how do I set this part : `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: select `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from default drop down and `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from attributes dropdown.

Comment: @black-room-boy let me know if you get it working.

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for. Big thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Well having a colomn that inserts a date on creation is one way to do it
then if you create a second column through php. collect the date and when you add or modify somthing have the php put the current date into the 2nd colomn

e.g.

```
$modifydate = Date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

$conn = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (DateModified,othercolomns) VALUES ('$modifydate ', '$othervalues')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

SQL Table

```
Datecreated, DateModyfied, [other colomns]
```